# getting limited inputs in python

Tags: python, input, split, limit, raiserror

As you can see the user has entered more than 3 numbers for the age-input and it is not correct to be like this.
What I want is to get limited numbers in my inputs, I mean if the quantity of students are 3 so how can I return an error if the user write more than 3 for it's height/weight/age ?

```
classAcounter=int(input("How many students? "))
classAlist=[]

height=input().split(" ")
weight=input().split(" ")
age=input().split(" ")

classAlist.append(height)
classAlist.append(weight)
classAlist.append(age)

print(classAlist)

#input:
3
175 170 183 188
70 68 83
18 19 18 19

output:
[['175', '170', '183', '188'], ['70', '68', '83'], ['18', '19', '18']]
```

Comment: you need to put in a Boolean test.  Look at if statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how:

```
classAcounter=int(input("How many students? "))
classAlist=[]

height = input().split(" ")
weight = input().split(" ")
age = input().split(" ")

if len(height)==len(weight)==len(age)==classAcounter:
    classAlist.append(height)
    classAlist.append(weight)
    classAlist.append(age)
else:
    print('Error: Inconsistent amount of info')

print(classAlist)
```

---

---

---

If you wish to ignore the extra values, and only append the wanted amount, here is a method similar to Sanket's, only we will be making use of the second parameter of the `str.split()` method to optimize the efficiency:

```
classAcounter=int(input("How many students? "))
classAlist=[]

height = input().split(" ",classAcounter)[:classAcounter]
weight = input().split(" ",classAcounter)[:classAcounter]
age = input().split(" ",classAcounter)[:classAcounter]

classAlist.append(height)
classAlist.append(weight)
classAlist.append(age)

print(classAlist)
```

You see, if we don't add the second parameter, if the user input many values, the program will first split *all* the values, even when we, like, only need the first 3.

Answer (score 0):

You could have done following:

```
classAcounter=int(input("How many students? "))
classAlist=[]

height=input().split(" ")[:classAcounter]
weight=input().split(" ")[:classAcounter]
age=input().split(" ")[:classAcounter]

classAlist.append(height)
classAlist.append(weight)
classAlist.append(age)

print(classAlist)
```

**#input:**

```
3
175 170 183 188
70 68 83
18 19 18 19
```

**output:**

```
[['175', '170', '183'], ['70', '68', '83'], ['18', '19', '18']]
```

However this can not limit the user from eterig multiple values but this can limit you from using all of the values entered by user.